# Unable to create a new table via EF Core Migration

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I have a class as follows:

User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

I created a EF Core migration to create a table based on the above class

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Users",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "NEWSEQUENTIALID()"),               
            Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 255),                
            Gender = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 255)               
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Users", x => x.Id);
        });
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
        name: "Users");
}

public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }       

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(t => t.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWSEQUENTIALID()");
    }

    public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

I need to create another table that has the same columns as `Users`:

```
public class InactiveUser : User
{        
    public Guid InactiveUserId { get; set; }
}

public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }       
    public DbSet<InactiveUser> InactiveUsers { get; set; }     

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(t => t.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWSEQUENTIALID()");
    }

    public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

When I run the migration, I see a new column `InactiveUserId` in the `Users` table instead of a new table `InactiveUsers`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create  a new table InactiveUsers , try the below code:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }       
        public DbSet<InactiveUser> InactiveUsers { get; set; }     

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(t => t.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWSEQUENTIALID()");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().UseTpcMappingStrategy()
            .ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<InactiveUser>()
                .ToTable("InactiveUsers");
        }

        public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

result:

[image]

You can read [Table-per-concrete-type configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-concrete-type-configuration)  to know more.